# How to make a proper Graph Api Request using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get user data using Graph API and jQuery but all I am getting is the username and user data.
Can anyone point out my mistake or anything that I am missing?
Please ignore any silly conceptual mistakes, if any, as I am new to jQuery.
Thanks a lot

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 var myToken = "EAACEdEose0cBAK93dc4Bx3mD4pVg5U8a2SZCl9tP9UF7TsbGH1SlGcboZAZCVcCgAeA3IEsjyQ4D58xAylHhZBjA0JMV2Jl1ZAfOlQ9wZC7wS01JzlX36V7YD5b3DXkn4ObNNT1AX4bZCQyU2bERQW1DsOFE894TNfs9WDcFBtH6ISRfLuFo8PqjL0XlUSDnOMZD";

 function myInfo(){
  $.ajax("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,id,user_hometown,age,birthday&access_token="+myToken,{
   success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
    console.log(typeof(response));
    $("#name").text(response.name);
    $("#email").text(response.email);
    $("#bday").text(response.birthday);
   }
  });
 } 
 $("#click").on('click', myInfo);


 function myFeeds(){
  $.ajax("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="+myToken,{
   success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
    console.log(typeof(response));
    $("#posts").text(response.posts);
   }
  });
 }
 $("#feeds").on('click', myFeeds);
});
```

```css
html, body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}

.container{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}

.container .row1{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.container #row1{
 margin-top: 2%;
 font-family: Roboto, "san-serif";
 font-size: 1.3em;
}

.container #row2{
 margin-top: 5%;
 font-family: Roboto, "san-serif";
 font-size: 1.2em;
}

.container #row3{
 margin-top: 8%;
 font-family: Roboto, "san-serif";
 font-size: 1em;
}

.container #row4{
 margin-top: 10%;
 font-family: Roboto, "san-serif";
 font-size: 1.2em;
}

a{
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Facebook Data Parser</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jQueryApp.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row" id="row1">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
     <div class="text-center">
      <span>My App</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" id="row2">
    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
     <div class="text-center">
      <span id="info">Hi, I am Abhinav. <a id="click">Click here to know more about me</a></span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" id="row3">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
     <div class="text-center">
      <span>User_name: <span id="name"></span></span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
     <div class="text-center">
      <span>User_email:<span id="email"></span></span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
     <div class="text-center">
      <span>User_birthday: <span id="bday"></span></span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" id="row4">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
     <div class="text-center">
      <span><a id="feeds">Check my recents feeds</a></span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryApp.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

I want to extract all the basic user data like hometown, birthday etc.

Comment: Did you request the necessary permissions to access that kind of data? And your second request is not requesting any feed data btw., since you're just requesting /me without asking for any fields or connections there.

Comment: i really hope you don´t plan to use that code in public. access tokens are meant to be kept secret.

Comment: @CBroe I realised what I was doing wrong, and I corrected it. Thanks:)

Comment: @luschn  I thought that this was short-term code so it would expire in an hour, nevertheless, i will careful next time:)

Comment: what i meant is that you should not use that javascript code on a website, because your token would be in the source...

Comment: also, why jquery instead of the official js sdk?

Comment: @luschn Just experimenting with jQuery. Actually, i am undergoing a course in Frontend Development. This was a project under that course.

Comment: in that case, i would recommend forgetting about jquery and learning vanilla js first - and then something like react. you really don´t need jquery anymore (except for bootstrap and some old plugins that rely on jquery).

Comment: a click handler is as easy with vanilla js, and there is the fetch api for ajax, for example ;)

Comment: @luschen Great. Finally happy to meet someone with same views. I know(actually love) vanilla js and can easily code the same app in vanilla js,. Its just that i have to upload this assignment to get to angular and react courses.Thanks for the comment though. :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I was making all the mistake expected from a beginner :)

The main errors were: 
    1. Not specifying the div to display the feed/post in my html file.
    2. Not making the required api request correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 var myToken = "EAACEdEose0cBAMNlP2TqSZAp7GDjeXaJ5FEKQlEMAf2zxV8irKaLi1hk6rLvEVdylZCrZCSbWrFyqwelZAx3Niw1eUXS4zIZAoIeNXkebc8aXrh8zBA6LnuCBXYr1dWXYJjjI8pFb3krgRp2hcoBCPcUsArPDECSvmNYZCuUxNP3BM4SwbsAY6nTxNgZBLfdV0ZD";

 function myInfo(){
  $.ajax("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email, name,birthday&access_token="+myToken,{
   success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
    console.log(typeof(response));
    $("#name").text(response.name);
    $("#email").text(response.email);
    $("#bday").text(response.birthday);
    
   }
  });
 } 
 $("#click").on('click', myInfo);

 function myFeeds(){
  $.ajax("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=feed&access_token="+myToken,{
   success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
    console.log(typeof(response));
    $("#post").text(response.feed.data[0].story);
   }
  });
 }
 $("#feeds").on('click', myFeeds);
});
```

```css
html, body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}

.container{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}

.container .row1{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.container #row1{
 margin-top: 2%;
 font-family: Roboto, "san-serif";
 font-size: 1.3em;
}

.container #row2{
 margin-top: 5%;
 font-family: Roboto, "san-serif";
 font-size: 1.2em;
}

.container #row3{
 margin-top: 8%;
 font-family: Roboto, "san-serif";
 font-size: 1em;
}

.container #row4{
 margin-top: 10%;
 font-family: Roboto, "san-serif";
 font-size: 1.2em;
}

a{
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Facebook Data Parser</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jQueryApp.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row" id="row1">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
     <div class="text-center">
      <span>My App</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" id="row2">
    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
     <div class="text-center">
      <span id="info">Hi, I am Abhinav. <a id="click">Click here to know more about me</a></span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" id="row3">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
     <div class="text-center">
      <span>User_name: <span id="name"></span></span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
     <div class="text-center">
      <span>User_email:<span id="email"></span></span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
     <div class="text-center">
      <span>User_birthday: <span id="bday"></span></span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" id="row4">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
     <div class="text-center">
      <span><a id="feeds">Check my recents Post</a>
       <div id="post"></div>
      </span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryApp.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```